# Question about semiclassical approach to QCD

Tags: gauge-theory, vacuum, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, semiclassical

I'm struggling to understand the usefulness of the semiclassical approach to QCD. In particular, by using this approach, we can analyze the vacuum structure of QCD, including theta-vacua, $n$-vacua, and tunneling effects in non-abelian gauge theories. However, as we all know, QCD is strongly coupled in the quantum regime, and therefore, our analysis does not provide any quantum mechanical insights. Am I correct? Is there anything robust that survives even in the quantum regime?